# MS Access validation rule for url

Tags: regex, validation, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm looking the way to validate a URL in Microsof Access. I could validate email formation but I can't get the correct regex for URL, when I put `http*`, I can form whatever it starts with http, but if I want to add an alternative `"s"` to this regex this way `https?` It only accepts https.

Answering @dbmitch : working at field validation level in table design with Access 2013.

Comment: What do you have now - you haven't posted anything to give us something to work with? Are you doing this at the field validation level in table design, or via VBA in a BeforeUpdate event? What version of MS-Access?

Comment: @dbmitch yes working at field validation level in table design with Access 2013

Comment: Your question is probably going to be closed soon if you don't update it with your current code you're using for working http and the non-working for https. I imagine you're using the Like operator, but we are all just guessing to this point

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious because there's probably a very valid reason I haven't thought of - but in nay case, why don't you just use the `Hyperlink` field type or was that not in Access 2013?

Comment: @dbmitch, yes, the field is in hyperlink format but that's not validation

Answer (score -1):

this is complex RegEx validation for Urls:

```
(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z
0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&%\$#\=~])*
```

Comment: Acces says, "the specified expression contains a non valid . (dot), ! (exclamation), or () (parenthesis).

Comment: Check the second one I added @AndrésChandía

Comment: RegEx at Access do not work as common RegEx applications, if I put only "(http|https)" it pops up the error window saying about non valid characters

Comment: I mean, the problem is not the regex but how to introduce it, for instance you can not do [0-9]{3} you have to do [0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: for an email validation I had to do ??*@??*.??*

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\
.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)` for email

Comment: The minute I add a "(" or a ")" there is an error message, even if I escape them